# How to merge Rx streams of different data

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

Here's a simplified scenario that I am trying to achieve with Rx.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
};

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
};

public class C
{
    public A MyA { get; set; }
    public IObservable<B> MyBObservable { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a data sequence

A(1, "Fred")

A(2, "Tom")

A(3, "Harry")

B(100, 1, "test")

B(101, 3, "xxx")

B(102, 1, "test2")

A(4, "Jane")

...

Note: There cannot be a B instance before the corresponding A instance.

I would like to get a result that looks like

C( A(1,"Fred"), IObservable ( B(100, 1, "test"), B(102,1, "test2") )

C( A(2, "Tom"), IObservable empty )

C( A(3, "Harry"), IObservable ( B(101, 3, "xxx") )

C( A(4, "Jane"), IObservable empty )

The result must include all instances of A (even when there are no B for that A yet)

I have some user code

```
IObservable<A> obsA = Observable.Create<A> { ... };
IObservable<B> obsB = Observable.Create<B> { ... };

obsB.Publish(); // shared

    // what goes here ?

obsB.Connect();
```

My current attempt uses SelectMany but does not quite do what I want as I only get entries where an A has a B appear. I also need those entries where A does not have a B.

Is it possible to do something like

```
obsA.SelectMany(a => new C { MyA = a, MyBObservable = obsB.Where(x => x.AId == a.Id) });
```

If it helps, obsA is a cold observable and will complete. obsB can be either a hot or cold observable. I am not bothered if C is observable or a list.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 1):

```
IObservable<A> obsA = Observable.Create<A> { ... };
IObservable<B> obsB = Observable.Create<B> { ... };

var c = from a in obsA
        join b in obsB on a.Id equals b.Id
        select new C(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more experimentation I have arrived at the following

```
obsA.Subscribe(a => new C (a, obsB.Where(x => x.AId == a.Id)));
```

and then in the constructor for C

```
public C (MyA a, IObservable<B> obsB)
{
    MyA = a;
    obsB.Subscribe(o => .. do something ...);
}
```

In my version, class C does not hold the observable but the results of doing something with each item returned.